# Create multiplication sequence

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a list of numbers from 0.001 to 1000 with multiplication of 10. So the list would be (0.001, 0.1, 10.....1000)

Is there any function for it?

```
a <- 0.0001
b <- 0.0001
for (i in 1:5) {
    b = b*100
    print(c)
    a <- c(a, b)

}
```

Can we replace the loop here with something more simple?

Comment: `10^(-3:3)`....

Comment: Note that `c(0.001, 0.1, 10, 1000)` is powers of `10` by increments of : `10^seq(-3, 3, by = 2)`.

Comment: thank you! I noticed the comments from above 10^(-3:3) and your suggestion 10^seq(-3, 3, by = 2) returns the same, is it a preference thing or one is more recommended to use?

Comment: `-3:3` is the same as `seq(-3,3)`, not `seq(-3,3,by=2)`. If you really want to go by multiplicative factors of 100, you really need the `by=2`. (Should your first sentence say "with multiplication of 100"?)

Comment: thanks for clarifying! 10^(-3:3) is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

It should be simple as:

```
0.001 * 10^(seq(0,6,2))
# > 0.001 * 10^(seq(0,6,2))
# [1]    0.001    0.100   10.000 1000.000
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the `GeometricSequence` function from the `bsts` package in such way:

`GeometricSequence(5, initial.value = 0.0001, discount.factor = 100)`

First argument - `length` (in an example it is 5) is a positive integer giving the length of the desired sequence. `initial.value` - the first term in the sequence. 
`discount.factor` - the ratio between a sequence term and the preceding term.